# Javascript DateTimePicker via MySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, jsp, javabeans

I am trying to implement a doctor's booking system using JSP, Java, SQL and JavaScript (DateTimePicker). I need a system where the available slots will be retrieved from the database for a certain doctor which will be display in the calendar.

I am having trouble with this whole section of the program as JavaScript is on the client-side so it won't be able to directly connect to the database.

Are there any suggestions in which this will be possible (where saved dates in the database will be retrieved and displayed on the DateTimePicker for a certain doctor)?

Thank You.

**Database**

```js
CREATE TABLE DOCTOR
(Doctor_id CHAR (20),
Doctor_foreman CHAR (20),
Doctor_surname CHAR (20),
CONSTRAINT PK_Administrator PRIMARY KEY (Doctor_id));

CREATE TABLE DOCTOR_AVAILABILITY
(Doctor_id CHAR(20),
AVAIL_DATES VARCHAR (20),
CONSTRAINT FK1_DOCTOR_AVAILABILITY FOREIGN KEY (Doctor_id) REFERENCES DOCTOR (Doctor_id));

INSERT INTO DOCTOR
VALUES (12345, "Matthew", "John");

INSERT INTO DOCTOR
VALUES (54321, "Hellen", "Kelly");
```

**index.jsp**

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<a href="drjohn.jsp">Dr John Availability</a><br>
<br>
<br>
<a href="drkelly.jsp">Dr Kelly Availability</a><br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

**drjohn.jsp**

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript">

var unavailableDates = ["12-2-2016", '13-2-2016'];

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(function () {
$('#txtCalendarDate1').datepicker({ 
 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    

 
 
 });
});
</script> 
<style>
.ui-datepicker th { background-color: ; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tblTest">
 <tr id="tr1">
 <td>Select appointment date: </td>
 <td><input type="text" id="txtCalendarDate1" value="" /></td>
 </tr>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Dr John Availability
<br>
<a href="index.jsp">Home Page</a><br>

</body>
</html>
```

**drkelly.jsp**

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript">

var unavailableDates = ["12-2-2016", '13-2-2016'];

function unavailable(date) {
    dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
    if ($.inArray(dmy, unavailableDates) == -1) {
        return [true, ""];
    } else {
        return [false, "", "Unavailable"];
    }
}

$(function () {
$('#txtCalendarDate1').datepicker({ 
 dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    beforeShowDay: unavailable,
    

 
 
 });
});
</script> 
<style>
.ui-datepicker th { background-color: ; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tblTest">
 <tr id="tr1">
 <td>Select appointment date: </td>
 <td><input type="text" id="txtCalendarDate1" value="" /></td>
 </tr>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
Dr Kelly Availability
<br>
<a href="index.jsp">Home Page</a><br>
<br>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX call to retrieve JSON data from the server (a list of doctors and the dates when they are free). Then perform the parsing of the JSON response. Dynamically create for each doctor so much instances of the `DateTimePicker`, 
how many dates corresponds to it. For each instance of the `DateTimePicker` set the date.